# Cancel background process when leaving a component to another?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am using this libray:

https://github.com/VadimDez/ng2-pdf-viewer

I have created a repository with an example of my problem.

https://github.com/YeisonVelez11/pdf

I am generating a pdf, and this works well. but if the pdf has not finished loading and I navigate to another component, I get an error.

Basically when I go back to a preview, I get a problem because the pdf that is being loaded can not be canceled. I do not know what trick I can do to get out of the document view at any time.

[image]

```
  <pdf-viewer [src]="archivo_adjunto"
              *ngIf="archivo_adjunto"
              [render-text]="false"
              [original-size]="true"
              [page]="1"
              [autoresize]="true"
              [show-all]="true"
              style="display: block;"
              (page-rendered)="pageRendered($event)"
  ></pdf-viewer>

ionViewDidLoad() {
this.archivo_adjunto="./assets/documents/Resumen Ejecutivo Autoevaluacion.pdf"

}
```

This is done in Ionic, but the functionality is in Angular.

Comment: If you can stop loading of PDF manually just add that code in `ngOnDestroy()`. It will get called when you change route and stop your process of loading PDF.

Comment: how can import that in ionic?

Comment: That seems like a **[bug in the library](https://github.com/VadimDez/ng2-pdf-viewer/issues/343)** but if the `(page-rendered)` event is triggered when the pdf is ready, you could prevent the user to close the page using the `ionViewCanLeave` lifecycle event. This is not a fix for the error, but a way to prevent it until the owner of the library fixes that issue. If you think this may help, please let me know and I'll write an answer with more details.

Comment: @sebaferreras you pretend that until the pdf has been rendered, the user can not leave the current view? I would like to see your solution, it is not an elegant solution but maybe it could work. I would like you to please show me how to do it, and if you have good behavior, the best answer will be yours.

Comment: @yavg  hi.. you got a solution for this ? else i can spend some time one the repo you shared.. please let me know ASAP.

Comment: Thanks... I dont have a solution  :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In large-scale apps or in components that deal with bunch of observables or subjects or BehaviorSubjects, it is good practice to unsubscribe the observables when you are leaving the component in order to prevent problems like memory leaks or slowing down system.

```
 ngOnDestroy(){
   this.ObservableOrSubsject1$.unsubscribe();
   this.ObservableOrSubsject2$.unsubscribe();
   ....
 }
```

Also do not forget to implement  OnDestroy to the class.

> export MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy

There is another good way that I actually like and you can use while dealing with subscriptions; in which you can provide a subject Like:

> private onDestroy$: Subject = new Subject();

and when using any observable (e.g: mapping or subscribing) pipe with takeUntil:

```
ngOnInit(){
   this.ObservableOrSubsject1
     .pipe(takeUntil(this.onDestroy$))
     .subscribe((result: IResult) => {
       this.result= Object.assign({}, result);
   });
```

and in ngOnDestroy just pass "this.onDestroy$.next()":

```
ngOnDestroy(){
   this.onDestroy$.next();
 }
```

Again, Do not forget to implement OnDestroy to the class.

At the end, **I recommend using Ngrx/Store and Ngrx/Effects** to manage your states and unify the events in your application; which will save you from lots of headaches and keeps your application in an standard architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [ng2-pdf-viewer/src/app/pdf-viewer/pdf-viewer.component.ts](https://github.com/VadimDez/ng2-pdf-viewer/blob/master/src/app/pdf-viewer/pdf-viewer.component.ts),

The `@Input() src` is checked in `loadPDF()`:

```
private loadPDF() {
    if (!this.src) {
      return;
    }
[. . .]
}
```

And this method is called on `ngOnChanges` event.

```
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (isSSR()) {
      return;
    }

    if ('src' in changes) {
      this.loadPDF();
    } else if [. . .]
  }
```

I believe you just have to change your value for `src` , which is currently in `archivo_adjunto`, into `undefined` or `null` in one of the lifecycle events of ionic when exiting a page. Perhaps on `ionViewWillLeave`, `ionViewWillUnload` or on `ngOnDestroy`. Changing the `src` value should trigger the `ngOnChanges` in the `PdfViewerComponent` which then calls the `loadPDF()`.

Let me know what worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just implement `OnDestroy` and define a method named `ngOnDestroy` in your component. Handle the cleanup/cancellation of ongoing work there.
This method will be automatically called whenever any component is removed from the DOM.

```
export class MyComponent implements OnDestroy() {
    //...

    ngOnDestroy() {
       // do the work here
    }

    //...
}
```